# Error in T-SQL trigger being ignored in .NET application

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I've got a TableAdapter and I'm calling the `Update(DataSet dataset)` function of the adapter.  There is a trigger on the underlying table that is throwing an error but this error is not causing an exception in the application after the select statement but it IS causing an exception if I just raise it at the beginning of the trigger.  Any ideas?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger1] 
   ON  [dbo].[table1]
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT a.description
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.b_id = a.b_id
INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.b_id = a.b_id AND i.a_id = a.a_id
WHERE a.code = i.code
AND b.b_id <> i.b_id
AND a.description <> i.description
AND b.code IN (SELECT code FROM b WHERE b_id = i.b_id)

IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('ERROR', 16, 1)
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN
END

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

Comment: Why do u have a SELECT statement in am UPDATE trigger? Also what kind of error is thrown?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see your select statement.

Comment: Added select statement, I need it to enforce a business rule.  I just don't understand why the placement of RAISERROR matters, how can a SELECT statement stop execution of the trigger so that the error doesn't get raised?

Comment: You could also use an `If Exists(Select...)` which would be much less overhead as your tables grow.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are examining `@@ROW_COUNT` to test for the existence of conflicting rows.  Perhaps an EXISTS query would meet your needs:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT a.description
    FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.b_id = a.b_id
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.b_id = a.b_id AND i.a_id = a.a_id
    WHERE a.code = i.code
    AND b.b_id <> i.b_id
    AND a.description <> i.description
    AND b.code IN (SELECT code FROM b WHERE b_id = i.b_id)
)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('ERROR', 16, 1)
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN
END
```

If the error still is not raised, then the business logic deserves a closer look.

Comment: Error isn't being raised even if I remove the IF altogether, unless I also remove the SELECT statement (so that the error is the only thing in the trigger).  So it's like the execution isn't getting past the SELECT statement.

Comment: Then the problem is in the logic of your SELECT statement (which seems complex to me).  Make sure your SELECT produces a row when the business rule is violated, and does *not* produce a row when the business rule is satisfied.  If you need to invert the logic, you can use `NOT EXISTS`.